# what does Array<T?> mean

Tags: android, arrays, generics, kotlin

When converting a java code into Kotlin, the

```
public MayData[] getDataArray() {
    return new MayData[0];
}
```

changed to

```
fun getDataArray(): Array<MyData> {
    return arrayOfNulls<MyData>(0)
}
```

but I got an error:

```
Error:(50, 16) Type mismatch: inferred type is Array<MyData?> but Array<MyData> was expected
```

it has to add the ‘?’

```
fun getDataArray(): Array<MyData?> {
    return arrayOfNulls<MyData>(0)
}
```

what does the ‘?’ mean with the template type?

Comment: ? marks a type as nullable. In Kotlin you make a distinction between types that can be null, and those that cannot.

Comment: T? is a Kotlin nullable type, Array<T?> just means that collection can contain nulls

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but not sure why asking a question is getting '-2', if whoever gave it could explain that would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return arrayOfNulls<MyData>(0)
```

What this line means:

- `arrayOfNulls` Return an array of N elements (zero in your case), but fill it with null
- `<MyData>` The Data-Type is `MyData`, which is NOT nullable

So you create an array with `null` values (even if the size is zero) but the DataType is not nullable:

Two solutions:

```
// zero elements in the array but not nullable
fun getDataArray(): Array<MyData> {
    return arrayOf()
}

// array with nullable data-type
fun getDataArray(): Array<MyData?> {
    return arrayOfNulls<MyData?>(0)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`arrayOfNulls` returns an array of objects, initialized with `null` values. The '?' means that the object may be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

`T` is a [generic](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html). `?` marks a type as nullable. In Kotlin you make a distinction between types that can be null, and those that cannot.

Since in Java all types except the atomic ones (`int`, `long`, `float`...) can be null you need to add the `?` operator to deal with this case as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to know that In Kotlin every class can be used in two variants: a nullable and a non-nullable one. For example, the class `String` can be used for the `String` or the `String?` type, the former one meaning "not null" and the latter one meaning "nullable".
2. The `<>` chars introduce a "generic type", e.g. for an `Array<String>` this means, that this Array can only hold objects of type `String`, whereas `Array<String?>` means it can hold instances of `String` and `null` on top of that.
3. As your making use of `arrayOfNulls` the function's return type will be `Array<MyData?>`, which is why the compiler complains:

> inferred type is Array but Array was expected
>   Blockquote

In order to fix that, you can either make your function return the nullable version, like you already did or you do not use `arrayOfNulls`, when you're sure you don't want to include `null`s in your array.

```
fun getDataArray(): Array<MyData?> {
    return arrayOfNulls<MyData>(0)
}
```

or

```
fun getDataArray(): Array<MyData> {
    return arrayOf<MyData>()
}
```